# Is there a setting for the adjustment brush in Lightroom that makes the "edit pins" disappear?

Tags: lightroom-5

Usually when using the adjustment brush in Lightroom a small "edit pin" appears in the center of the adjustment made.

For some reason this feature has stopped working. Is this a setting I can set (to off) myself or is this a result of a bug in the program?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean "Edit Pins" when writing "dot handle", you can turn those on in the bottom left of the image frame:

[image]

Alternatively you can press <kbd>H</kbd> to toggle the edit pins.

Comment: Perfect! I meant edit pins, just didn't know the term. Unfortunately this only solves half of the problem. I still can drag the image around when zooming in. I think it's not related though and fits better in another question.

Comment: @Hugo Oh, I didn't notice that part of the question… But, yeah probably that's better suited for a separate question.